# how do i close fullscreen in cheese

Tags: cheese

I have a HP 6vt and once I put cheese in full screen it has no way to move back to a window since nothing on my computer works at that point except the off button.I even went to software center and un-installed cheese and then re-installed it and as soon as I  open cheese it goes to fullscreen and nothing will close it except restarting the computer. I have tried the <kbd>F11</kbd> button and alt cheese but nothing works once the computer starts cheese.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F11</kbd> should work as [it is the key putting it in fullscreen](http://library.gnome.org/users/cheese/unstable/full-screen.html.en) in the first place.

To **kill cheese** you should be able to log into another tty session using for example <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>. Once logged in, type:

```
killall cheese
```

Then go back to your graphical session with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.

I would also suggest:

- uninstall using the `--purge` option:
  `sudo apt-get remove --purge cheese`
- start cheese from the terminal grabbing the output:
  `cheese 2>&1 > cheese.log`
  The produced log file might give you a clue about why it is acting up.
- if none of this works  you might have hit a new bug.